# Removing elements from linked list using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list, pthreads, mutex

I have a x number of threads and I need them to remove elements from a linked list but only when the list is not empty. However, I don't want them to die if the list is empty since I'm using a named pipe to add new elements whenever I want. I'm facing a problem while checking if the linked list is empty, if it has 1 element all of my threads will enter the condition and the second thread will crash the program.

```
void threads(){
    while(1){
        if(isEmtpy!=1){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);       
            //work
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I suppose I need to change the location of my mutex but if I put it before my if condition nothing will happen.

Comment: Use a semaphore to count the elements in the list, ie. wait on it at the top of the loop.  You will then not need the 'isEmtpy' check at all and avoid the CPU and memory-bandwidth wasting polling.  Post a unit to the sema whenever you add an element to the list.

Comment: Wouldn't that only remove elements if the number of elements was the same as the number of threads?

Comment: ?? It would remove alements as fast as the threads can eat them up. Do you mean that several items are added at a time, and you want one thread only remove them all from the list?   Would that not leave the other threads needlessly idle?  For example: if there are 8 threads, and 3 items are added, do you want just one of the 8 threads to remove all 3 items, or three threads to remove one each?

Comment: I want 3 threads to remove 1 each, but I guess the solution I found will work for now. It's probably not the most efficient way to do it but that won't be a problem. Thank you anyways.

Comment: 'I want 3 threads to remove 1 each' - so, semaphore, as I suggested earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the lock higher, to protect the `isEmpty` variable as well should be enough

```
void threads(){
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);       
        if(isEmtpy!=1){
            //work
            isEmpty = hasElements(list) ? 0 : 1;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The changes to `isEmpty` should also occur within the critical section.

Comment: I was doing that and it wasn't working because I wasn't unlocking the mutex if the list was empty, just added an else and it's working now. Thank you!